# get_the_category vs wp_get_post_categories

Tags: categories

There are two functions that apparently serve the same purpose of retrieving a list of categories from a post:

- `get_the_category()`
- `wp_get_post_categories()`

What are the difference between those two and when should I prefer each? Are there any caveats I should be aware?

Comment: `get_the_category()` is more simple than `wp_get_post_categories()`. on `get_the_category()`you can only pass a post id and on `wp_get_post_categories()` you can pass the post id and several arguments (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/).

Comment: `get_the_category()` is limited for retrieval of category of single post without any restrictions while `wp_get_post_categories()` give you way to apply constraints on your result.